# python gather together ascii and utf-8 stuff

Tags: python, encoding, codec

I have a text file "words.txt" that contains english words. Let's assume it contains just three words: "one", "two" and "three".
I also have three files: one.dat, two.dat and three.dat. Each of these files contains binary data representing transcription of corresponding word. Format is UTF-8.
What do I want: I want to combine "words.txt" and all these .dats into single document that I would be able to print. So I need something like this (lets' name it "final.dat"):

one   [wan]
two   [tu:]
three [?ri:]

but with correct "th" sign instead of "?" :)

The most important thing is that I must be able to load "final.dat" into MSWord or Writer and print it out.

I'm going to accomplish it by python, but I'm really got stuck with all these 'codecs', 'encodes', 'decodes' and so on...

Comment: If they have binary data, then you do not have UTF-8.  And vice versa. UTF-8 is no more binary data than ASCII is.  Both are text data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x, reading a UTF-8 file can be accomplished using

```
open('one.dat').read().decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
codecs.open('one.dat', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

both of which return a Python `unicode` object. If you want to turn a `str` (ASCII/binary string) `s` into a `unicode`, use `s.decode('utf-8')`.

In Python 3.x, do just

```
open('one.dat').read()
```

or

```
open('one.dat', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

The idea is that a `str` (Py2.x) or `bytes` (Py3.x) object contains just the binary representation of a string in *some* encoding without specifying which encoding that is; the `decode` method turns this into a proper Unicode string (`unicode` in 2.x, `str` in 3.x).

(Btw., UTF-8 is not "binary data", it's just text in a non-ASCII encoding.)

Comment: The builtin name `bytes` exists in 2.x (at least 2.6) as well. It's an alias for `str` there.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. But I still have 2 questions. 1) Are you sure I must use "s.decode", not "s.encode" to turn ascii string into unicode? 2) After I make them all "unicode", and try to write into file, it crashes: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0259' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) (I use f3.write(unicode_string))

Comment: @Nick: decoding is turning something into Unicode; encoding is turning Unicode into a specific format such as UTF-8 or ASCII. So you may need to `encode` before writing the data out. Use the `encoding` kwarg to `open`/`codecs.open` when opening the output file, then just write `unicode` objects to it.

Comment: I much prefer your solutions that put the `encoding='utf-8'` argument right there in the `open` over those that monkey around with binary data by hand.  I can think of only one situation over the last several years where I had to read the file in binary because it contained data whose encoding varied from line to line. Manual decoding and encoding is a terrible pain. The stream encoding is the clean and clear way to go.